# when observing sql table using sql dependency got permission error

Tags: c#

Error  accepting connection: {0} Incorrect syntax near '/'. Changed database context to 'LDMDb'. Current user must have following permissions: [CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SERVICE, CREATE QUEUE, SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS, CONTROL, REFERENCES] that are required to start query notifications.

when i'm trying to get table change data like observe table record that are insert,update or delete as per change i want to notify client

can you please provide me the solution for that..
i'm creating hardware central server for all socket machine and api will inert record in database table and give command for changed or insert and i have to observe table change as per command and notify to client...

Comment: What code did you use to create the SqlDependency?

Comment: using  this procedure SQL_PERMISSIONS_INFO ,SQL_FORMAT_CREATE_INSTALLATION_PROCEDURE,SQL_FORMAT_CREATE_UNINSTALLATION_PROCEDURE

Comment: I don't know what those procedures are, they look to be custom written. Please show all relevant code

Comment: yes this is custom written and i have solved that thanks for your support @Charlieface